# Divisibility by $8$ for permutations of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **Moderator's note**: This is an [on-going contest problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/mar14/challenges/manasa-loves-maths). Per usual protocol the answers have been hidden and the question is locked until after the contest ends. (21.03.2014)

Given an integer $N$. How to check if there is a permutation of digits of integer $N$ that is divisible by $8$?

Example: Let $N = 61$ then answer is "YES" as $16$ is a permutation of $N$ that is divisible by $8$.

What's the best way to check if $N$ can be very large.

Comment: What does the divisibility test for powers of 2 tell you?

Comment: @rah4927 What you mean? I didnt get you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that a number is a multiple of 8 if and only if its last three digits are a multiple of 8.  So it is enough to locate, somewhere within $N$'s digits, three that can form a three-digit multiple of 8.

Now there are exactly 95 possible sets of three digits that can be rearranged to a multiple of 8, so the algorithm should have a list of them prepared ahead of time.  This list $\def\L{\mathscr L}\L$ can be searched in constant time.

> ```
>     000 002 004 006 008 012 014 016 023 024 025
>     027 028 029 034 036 044 045 046 047 048 049 056
>     067 068 069 088 112 123 125 126 127 128 129 136
>     144 146 148 166 167 168 223 224 227 234 235 236
>     238 239 244 246 247 248 255 256 257 258 259 267
>     269 278 279 288 289 299 336 344 348 356 367 368
>     369 445 446 447 448 449 456 458 466 468 469 478
>     488 489 566 567 568 669 677 678 679 688 689 888
> ```

Associate with each item $i$ in $\L$ the corresponding $m(i)$ which is a multiple of 8.  For example, $m(367)$ is $736$.

Associate with each item $i$ in $\L$ a number $n(i)$, initially 0.  This tracks the number of digits of $i$ that have been seen in $N$.  For example, if we have seen a 3 and a 7 in $N$ but not a 6, then  $n(367)$ will be 2.  If $n(i)$ reaches 3 for any $i$, then we know that all the digits of $i$ have all been found, and by putting them at the end in the right order, we will have a multiple of 8. (The right order is given by $m(i)$, which is computed ahead of time.)

There is a small complication because $i$ might have repeated digits, but that is not too hard to take care of.  We will keep a counter $c(d)$ of the number of times each different digit is seen, for this purpose.

If $N$ has fewer then three digits, we must deal with it as a special case. (I said earlier we should pad it with zeroes; this is wrong.)

Then we scan the digits of $N$.  When we see the digit $d$, increment $c(d)$.

Say that $c(d)$ now has the value $c$. Scan the elements of $\L$ looking for those that contain at least $c$ instances of digit $d$.  Increment $n(i)$ for each $i$ that contains at least $c$ instances of digit $d$.  (Note that when $c>3$, we can omit the scan entirely, since no item has more than 3 instances of any digit.)

If, after a scan, any item $i$ has $n(i)=3$, halt;  $N$ can be permuted to a multiple of 8.  If the three digits of item $i$ are `abc`, simply permute $N$ so that `abc` appear at the end in the right order as given by $m(i)$. For example, if item $i$ is `235`, you need to search $N$ for a `2`, a `3`, and a `5`, and put them at the end in the order `352`.  The order of the other digits does not matter.

Otherwise, after processing the last digit of $N$, halt.  $N$ cannot be  permuted to form any multiple of 8

This takes time proportional to the number of digits of $N$; up to a constant factor, this is optimal.

---

Pseudocode:

- Initialize the following variables:

  - `L[1]...L[95] = {000, 002, 004, 006, ..., 689, 888 }` as above
  - `m[1]...m[95] = {000, 200, 040, 600, ..., 896, 888 }` corresponding multiples of 8
  - `n[1]...n[95] = {0,0,...,0}`, number of digits of `L[i]` that have been seen so far
  - `c[0]...c[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` number of instances of digit $d$ that have been seen so far

And suppose that $N$ is an $n$-digit number whose digits are in `N[1]...N[n]`.

> ```
> for i in 1 to n do:  
>   d ← N[i]  
>   c[d] ← c[d]+1  
>   if c[d] < 4 then:  
>     for j from 1 to 95 do:  
>       if L[j] has at least c[d] copies of digit d:  
>         n[j] ← n[j] + 1  
>         If n[j] = 3 HALT and output "yes" and the value of m[j]  
>       end if
>     end for j  
>   end if   
> end for i
> ```
>
> HALT and output "no"

The value of $m[j]$ emitted with "yes" tells you which three digits of $N$ to move to the end to obtain a multiple of 8.

A more efficient algorithm replaces the repeated linear scan of $\L$ with a preselection of 30 sublists, with sublist $10a+b$ containing all the elements of $\L$ that have at least $a+1$ occurrences of digit $b$.  But this and other such optimizations are engineering details.

Comment: Do you believe that looking for a number in a list of 95 is more efficient than making the division by 8?

Comment: Making what division by 8, exactly?

Comment: the Euclidian division of a number with 3 digits with divisor 8, keeping only the reminder.

Comment: What number with three digits?

Comment: @MJD Could you please bind up your answer by some pseudocode or so?

Comment: @MJD I just want Yes or No .No need of the permutation providing that result.So i think their is no need of m[]

Comment: Quite so! You can omit $m$ if you only want yes or no.

Comment: @mookid is suggesting that testing for membership in the list `L` is probably more efficiently done by `x % 8 == 0` rather than `x in L`.

Comment: @hurkyl But there is no test for membership in the list `L`. Instead we need to select *all* the elements of `L` which match a certain criterion ("contains at least `c[d]` instances of digit `d`") , and increment *all* the corresponding counters `n[i]`. There is no way this can be reduced to a single division.

Comment: Shouldn't your "contains at least `c[d]` instances of digit `d`" instead be *at most*? I think a simpler algorithm (to state, at any rate) is to scan $N$ once, compute the array $c(N)$ (that is, $c(N)[d]$ contains the number of times digit $d$ occurs in $N$), and then test for each item $i$ in $L$ whether $c(N) \ge c(i)$ elementwise. This is also linear-time, and we could also precompute the $c(i)$'s.

Comment: Is there bug in the following implementation of @MJD 's comment? Ps- brilliant explanation! but i guess its giving some wrong outputs! can anyone find errors?
<a href="http://ideone.com/FPzeVr"> here is the link! </a> thanks!

Comment: @SunnyPatel I haven't looked closely at your implementation, but the example run you have on that page has the input `201` and the output `YES`, which is correct. What is an example where it produces the wrong answer?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I don't think it should be “at most”. When you see the second `0`, you need to increment the digits-seen count for a pattern like `000` or `008`, but not for `023`, where a second `0` doesn't help. I agree that preprocessing the $L[i]$ as you say is a useful optimization.

Comment: Sorry i misread your comment. Anyway i was just pointing out that the following simpler algorithm: "scan N to calculate c(N), then loop over L and check whether c(i) <= c(N) for some i" is also linear time, and we don't need the n(i). Of course it's linear time for all inputs unlike your algorithm that can break early.

Comment: Yes, I agree. ${}{}$

Comment: Actually, how about doing the scan over L after each digit of N read? It too takes time linear in the number of digits of N that need to be read until some three digits that can be permuted to a multiple of 8 exist, and is optimal up to a constant factor, but doesn't need the n(i)s. Is this simpler algorithm worse than the one you described?

Answer (score 2):

Criterion of divisibility by 8: the integer formed with the last 3 digits is divisible by 8.

Now if $N$ is large, try to find 3 digits to create a number with this particularity.

Comment: Checking for triplets means selecting 3 numebrs of N which is done in nC3 ways which can be very large.So i dont find it useful here.N can go upto 10^110

Comment: First, you know that the last digit must be even. Then, check that the last 2 digits form a multiple of 4. This take around $O(n^2)$, then check for the remaining digits, amother $O(n)$, for a total of $O(n^2)$.

Comment: It doesnt fit for 16

Comment: Actually, a more accurate way is to check for the remaining digits as soon as you find an admissible pair, which does not improve the worst case scenario complexity, but the average sould be linear.

Comment: @user3001932 it fits if you write 16 = 016.

Comment: @user3001932,16=016.Also,16 doesn't qualify as an extremely large number.

Comment: I downvoted this because while the idea is sound, it waves its hands  by saying "try to find 3 digits".  Doing this efficiently is precisely the  interesting part of the problem.

Comment: I wrote this solution because this is a math forum, and OP did not ask for a linear algorithm to find the permutation.

Comment: I downvoted this too, for leaving out the actually hard part of the question by just saying "try to find 3 digits": *how* do you find such 3 digits? That's the point of the question. The question from its very first question asks "Whats the best way to check it if N can be very large" — if you don't care at all about efficiency, then "for each permutation of the digits of N, check divisibility by 8" would work just as well, and be even more straighforward to state.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a divisibility rule for 8:

Let $n=\ldots a_4a_3a_2a_1$.

- If $a_3$ is even, then $n$ is divisible by 8 if $a_2a_1$ is divisible by 8.
- If $a_3$ is odd, then $n$ is divisible by 8 if $a_2a_1$ is divisible by 4 but not 8.

The two digit numbers divisible by 8 are

> 00, 08, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96,

and the two digit numbers divisible by 4 but not 8 are

> 04, 12, 20, 28, 36, 44, 52, 60, 68, 76, 84, 92.

Thus a number with three or more digits has a permutation by its digits that is divisible by 8 if it

- contains a pair of digits present in the first list and at least one other digit that is even,

or if it

- contains a pair of digits present in the second list and at least one other digit that is odd.

Thus the number 6295 has such a permutation (9256), since it contains the digits 6 and 5 (as in 56) and the even number 2.

By the way, this would be soo much easier if we were checking for divisibility by 3 ;P

Comment: @JonaGranholm What will you say for 200 ?

Comment: oops. Edited :P